# Serializer fields in standard JSON representation

Tags: django-rest-framework

What is the best way to return serializer fields in JSON standard representation. For example fields such as `user_id` in django model return as `userId` JSON field. Without using `SerializerMethodField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this package](https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case). Though it's been 2 years since the last commit, it works fine and seems to do what you want.